# Android - JPG or PNG for app background

Tags: android, image, png, jpeg

In my Android app I have a screen which has a corkboard background which takes up the entire screen.

Right now I'm using different PNGs for different densities, but I have found that this drawable is the one which is taking the most space of my APK, so I want to reduce its size.

I was reading this [post](https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/smallerapk-part-6-image-optimization-zopfli-webp-4c462955647d#.37za44fa6) and now I'm wondering whether I should use JPG or WebP for my background instead of PNG. The background, as I said before, is a corkboard.

So, what do you suggest me: stick with PNG, Zoplify the PNG or move to JPG or WebP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPG also but size should be in KB to maintain APK Optimization

For background purpose JPG with small size is good approch

if you are concern with the icon then in that case PNG will be more useful

even i used JPG for background purpose in my app with small size & its works great with more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Use JPG where you don't need transparency and PNG when you do.

This means: JPG for background, PNG for other items.

This is the standard today. Stick with it unless you have a good reason not to (vectorial images etc.)